# Trying to test a gateway in spring integration using mockito, but when autowiring the gateway its always null

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Trying to test a gateway in spring integration using mockito but when autowiring the gateway its always null.

I am using annotations to create a context for writing the test case, but the mockito and annotations are all  working weird. 
Getting no support or basic understanding that what is going wrong here.

Can anyone please suggest a simple way or how to test a spring integration flow, which starts with a gateway. As the value for the gateway is coming null for me in the test.

---

we are using java annotations to define the spring integration flow like below :

public class integrationFlow()

{

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface EnterHere{
     @Gateway(requestChannel = "requestChannel") 
     void process(DtoObject dtoObject)
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(requestChannel)
                .filter()
                 //... its a big flow with lot of interactions  
                .get();
}
```

}

I have written a test case that will create an object with default values that will be passed to the dto and that will trigger the flow of spring integration. 
i want to use mockito here as there are lots of dependencies in the project.

i am using

```
@Autowired
private EnterHere enterhere
```

and in contextconfguration for the test case i am defining

```
@MessagingGateway
    public interface EnterHere{
         @Gateway(requestChannel = "requestChannel") 
         void process(DtoObject dtoObject)
    }
```

But when in the test case

```
@Test
public void testGateway(){
     enterHere.process(this.dtoObjectMock)
     // i am always getting a null value at this enterhere.
}
```

We are not using Spring boot , we are using Mockito annotations, @Mock and @InjectMocks ,@Runwith(MockitoJunit4Runner.class) like these

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, could you provide a minimal example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Hi Tomasz i have tried to add a few more details to my question ,i m really stuck here, the test case is not able to get a value in the gateway and hence the whole integration flow is not being tested.

Comment: What annotations are you using on your test class?  Are you using spring boot?  This is the type of additional information needed.